# How to override customer login.phtml and customer_account_login.xml file in custom module Magento 2?

Tags: overrides, customer-account, magento2.3.1, social-buttons

I need to customize a customer login form. I need to **add social media button** in that page as well as register page.

So please give me a solution with `customer_account_login.xml` and `Login.php` update and How?

**Tried:**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

i did in custom module Lucent\SocialLogin\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_login.xml but not workin

Comment: You can call your phtml file of social media button in customer_account_create.xml file and customer_account_login.xml file.

Comment: <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>  i did in custom module Lucent\SocialLogin\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_login.xml  but not working

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Lucent\SocialLogin\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 2. Put your content in Lucent\SocialLogin\view\frontend\templates\form\login.phtml
> 3. Add remain module require Files and folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your need to changes to

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_login" template="Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml">
```

**From**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

You no need to add **referenceContainer**.

Also make 
`module.xml` of `Lucent_SocialLogin` should dependable of  `Magento_Customer`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Lucent_SocialLogin" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/> <!-- add dependable -->
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: <referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Lucent_SocialLogin::form/login.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer> working this thanks sir

Comment: You have add some extra code.It do not need.

Comment: Ok, sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is two  solution  you can  use  , By Overriding controller and  plugin (Recommended according to magento  guide lines) you can  customise the changes you wanna  do  :

**Plugin Implementation :**

Add following file : app/code/Verdor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login">
        <plugin name="change_login" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\LoginPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
```

- Add Plugin  file in following location (Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\LoginPlugin) and  choose your plugin type  from following before, after, around .

  ```
  namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer;
  ```

  use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login;

  ```
  class LoginPlugin
  {
  public function afterExecute(Login $subject, $result)
      {
  '''''''''''''
  '''''''''''''
  }
  }
  ```

**Layout Override:** 
 Add following file  in  location :

```
app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_login.xml

Here , YOu can apply  your changes for frontend here, Magento  first execute this file , with  your changes  , (Just simply following fallback  mechanism  here ).
```